# WordPress Multisite - Different admin theme on different site

Tags: wordpress

I want to set different color on the dashboard of each site (in my multisite). For example the first site is based on the user's preference, but the second one always use **Midnight** theme.

Is there a way to set this in functions.php?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just found it on other's question. Put this on functions.php.

```
add_filter('get_user_option_admin_color', 'change_admin_color');
function change_admin_color($result) {
  if(get_current_blog_id() === 2) {
    return 'midnight';
  }
  else {
    return $result;
  }
}
```